# Is it possible to redirect all other requests from example.com via PAC list?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

Assuming I visit `example.com`, which makes megaton of requests to:

- googleads
- googletracking shit
- other ads
- payment services
- captchas
- etc

and I want all these requests to go through proxy as well, not just `*example.com` requests (via `shExpMatch(host, '*example.com')`) PAC rule, but I want to do so ONLY when `window.location.origin` is `example.com`, I dont want to do this globally, which is what will happen if I do `shExpMatch(host, '*cloudflare.com')`.

Is such thing possible in Chromium-based browsers with PAC list rules?